# LibreOffice Calc function localization

Tags: libreoffice-calc, localization, lubuntu

I'm using LibreOffice 3.4.3 on [Lubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu). The locale I'm using is es_AR, I installed LibreOffice with `sudo apt-get install libreoffice`, then installed the Spanish language package with Synaptics (`libreoffice-l10n-es`).

So far, so good, the menus and the interface in general is translated to Spanish, **but**
in Calc the formulas remain in English (eg SUM() instead of SUMA()). If I enter SUMA(A1:B1) manually, the result is `#NAME?` . The option

> Preferences->Calc->Formulas->Use the formulas in english

is unchecked (I see this option in spanish, of course)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Do some function names in Calc appear in english others in local language (mixed up)?

See [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/873702)

> launchpad.net > Ubuntu > “libreoffice” package > Bugs > Bug #873702

Comment: This bug has now been marked as Resolved Fixed, and was released in version 3.5.0-beta2.